# PayPal Rest API Invoice WebHook

Tags: php, rest, paypal

I am having a very hard time figuring out whether it is even possible, but here is the task I want to do. Whenever an invoice that is created by my merchant account, I want PayPal to send a webhook to my webserver notifying that the invoice has been paid for. I can find full documentation on how to do that for simple payments, but there is literally nothing documented on how to do that with an invoice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/) can be used for this.

When a PayPal invoice is paid the PayPal server will POST transaction data including the PayPal invoice ID and any custom invoice ID you supply with the original invoice.  That way you can automate procedures based on the transaction data.

IPN works with all payments, refunds, disputes, etc. on your account.  It's a very useful tool.

Comment: Is IPN still the right path?  I've been trying to get Webhooks or IPN working in the sandbox but the webhook never seems to get called and I can't figure out how to specify the IPN notify url when sending an invoice via the rest api.

Comment: You need to setup an IPN URL in the sandbox seller account that you're working with, and you'll need to do the same with the live account, too.  Invoicing IPN's are triggered based on that since there is no NotificationURL parameter included in the CreateInvoice API.